# How do I make my program re-run a certain line of code?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a game and I have js prompt the person to allocate all of their skill points. When they take damage or heal they need to hit a button to change the value of their health stat. The problem is, when they put in the new value, all of the buttons to edit stats and roll a d20 disappear

for reference, at the beginning of the program, after the player decides all of their stats, it displays all of their stats with their values, and buttons to roll for each stat and edit their hp value.

this is roughly what I have

```
<script src="javascript.js">
</script>

<script>
    function hpChange() {
        var health = prompt('What is your new HP value?');
        document.write(prints all of the stats with their values);
    }
</script>

<form>
    <input type="button" onclick="hpChange()" value="Change HP"/>
</form>
```

(this is my own version of DnD i play with friends with custom rules)

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEqNj.jpg)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK2j0.jpg)

Comment: I recommend that you don't use `document.write()`. I think it would be better if you append to the page or edit an existing element on the page to display the content.

Comment: I wouldn't even use `prompt` for input

Comment: `all of the buttons to edit stats and roll a d20 disappear` Could you please share with us code of this parts? Also why do you have an emply script tag in your code?

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to manipulate the document  via its elements. 
For example, you can represent stats as a list of items in your HTML code:

index.html :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
    <!-- Here we assign a unique ID to the element to get it later in our JS file -->
      <li id="hp">HP: 10</li>
      <li>STR: 5</li>
      <li>AGI: 5</li>
      <li>INT: 5</li>
      <li>CHA: 5</li>
      <li>PER: 5</li>
      <li>LUC: 5</li>    
    </ul>
     <!-- Here we assign a unique ID to the button to get it later in our JS file -->
   <button id="rollForHealth">
   Roll for Health
   </button>
   <!-- It's better to link an outer JS file at the bottom of the page to initialize it when the content is loaded -->
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And there is an outer JS file that will change values of the stats:

javascript.js :

```
//we bind our HP element to a variable
const hp = document.getElementById('hp');
//we bind our button to its own variable
const rollForHp = document.getElementById('rollForHealth');

//create an eventlistener and bind it to the button
rollForHp.addEventListener('click', healthRoll, false);

/*
This function will bind prompt input to a variable and change
element inner HTML instead of refreshing the whole document
*/
function healthRoll() {
  let result = prompt('What is your new HP value?');
  hp.innerHTML = `HP: ${result}`
}
```

That's how it works  on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Addeu/o2axk1s4/39/)

You may do the same with the other stats.

I hope it will help and you will enjoy your sessions in DnD.